# Simple Salesforce: How do I convert leads

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I've started using simple-salesforce python library to implement SOAP API calls from python app. This has worked great for the most part, but I can't find the ability to convert leads. Can anyone help me with this?

This is a core functionality/process of the system and I'm sure it must exist, but I cannot find it despite it existing within the [API docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_convertlead.htm). Perhaps this is just now a customized lead update?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple uses REST API, convertLead call is available only in SOAP API. The functional gap is Salesforce's fault, not simple's dev team.

You can expose a piece of Apex as a REST webservice and call that from simple: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/50045/799.

Or you can use simple just for login and use the session id + hand-crafted XML (or a proper SOAP client?) to call the SOAP API?

Comment: Thanks for the clarity on the matter! I'll try the latter you suggested